# Compilation Dependency when using Vitamio Library

Tags: android, gradle, vitamio

I am trying to edit MediaController in Vitamio module library. But compilation Dependency error is stopping from compilation. so effect is not seen in player. ":app" compilation completes successfully but ":vitamio" compilation is completes with error unsuccessful.

```
Warning:Dependency app:unspecified on project vitamio resolves to an APK archive which is not supported as a compilation dependency. File: ..\app\build\outputs\apk\app-release-unsigned.apk
```

:app gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.app.appdotcom"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "0.1.2"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

android {
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.0.0@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
compile 'com.android.support:leanback-v17:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:preference-leanback-v17:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
compile 'de.greenrobot:greendao:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.1.0'
compile 'me.neavo:vitamio:4.2.2'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.3.0'
}
```

:vitamio gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

dependencies {
compile project(':app')
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 23
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
    }

}

}
```

Comment: you cannot use an unsigned version as your dependency

Comment: so what should i exactly do to resolve this?? :)